# Xamarin.Forms: wrong button text alignment after click (Android)

Tags: android, layout, alignment, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms (version 1.2.2) on Android (Nexus 5).
The alignment of `Button.Text` is often not centered after performing a click.

In a short project, I figured out, that updating the UI causes the problem.

```
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {   
        var label = new Label {
            Text = "label",
        };
        var buttonBad = new Button {
            Text = "buttonBad",
            Command = new Command(() => label.Text += "1"),
        };
        var buttonGood = new Button {
            Text = "buttonGood",
        };

        return new ContentPage { 
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    buttonBad,
                    buttonGood,
                    label,
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

A click on "buttonBad" (updating the `label.Text`) causes the text-alignment of this button to not be centered anymore. A click on "buttonGood" does not cause the problem.

Is there a good workaround to solve this problem?

This workaround seems to be too complicated:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20608/fix-for-button-layout-bug-on-android

[image]

**edit:**
A programatically edit of the UI also cases the bug. Changing the `label.Text` in an async method after a short waiting leads the "buttonGood" to align its text wrong after a click.

**edit2:**
I created an example / test project on GitHub:
https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/ButtonTextAlignmentBug.git
The alignment is correct, when the StackLayout is replaced by an AbsolutLayout, but i need the StackLayout to work well.

Comment: Note that clicking on the "good button" only works without realignment until the "bad button" was clicked the first time.

Comment: Still present even in 1.2.3-prerelease 4.

Comment: Same issue here. Hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: Here is a discussion right now http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24956/xamarin-forms-1-2-3-prerelease-4-out#latest

Comment: Still present in 1.2.3 release :\ this is just madness

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, after hours of dealing with this silly bug, I resolved it by implementing a custom renderer and overriding `ChildDrawableStateChanged`:

```
public override void ChildDrawableStateChanged(Android.Views.View child) 
{
    base.ChildDrawableStateChanged(child); 
    Control.Text = Control.Text; 
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: Setting `HeightRequest = 20` (or similar value) and `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` for the two buttons makes the caption jump again, even with this fix (tested on XF 1.2.3). But this is an unlikely constellation, I guess.

Comment: Did you write this as a custom renderer for button?

Comment: Hi @LucasMouraVeloso yes, I implemented it as a renderer to apply on all the buttons within the application