# Xamarin.Forms Switch Control is not Visible on Android prior to selecting an Entry Control

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Registration Form which looks roughly like this

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        Padding="{x:Static local:Styles.LabelBeforeEntryPadding}">
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding LabelPasswort2}" 
            HorizontalOptions="{x:Static local:Styles.LabelHorizontalOptions}" 
            TextColor="{x:Static local:Styles.RegistrationPageTextColor}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <custom:StrypeEntry 
        Text="{Binding Passwort2}" 
        IsPassword="true" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ControlsEnabled}" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
<!--Newsletter-->
<StackLayout 
    Orientation="Horizontal" 
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Switch 
        IsToggled="{Binding Newsletter}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ControlsEnabled}" 
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
    <Label 
        Text="{Binding LabelNewsletter}" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
        TextColor="{x:Static local:Styles.RegistrationPageTextColor}" />
</StackLayout>
<!--Datenschutz-->
<StackLayout 
    Orientation="Horizontal" 
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <custom:StrypeSwitch 
        IsToggled="{Binding Privacy}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ControlsEnabled}" 
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <Label 
        Text="{Binding LabelPrivacy}" 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
        WidthRequest="300" TextColor="{x:Static local:Styles.RegistrationPageTextColor}" />
</StackLayout>
```

The Problem is that the Switches are not visible when displaying the Form, they only become visible when an entry is focused.

The StrypeEntry is just a customized Entry with Border Corder and a prop for Capitalize, nothing fancy and for the switch I made a Custom Renderer to fix the issue of not displaying.

I already tried the fix for the ButtonText Alignment which did not help ([Xamarin.Forms: wrong button text alignment after click (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056519/xamarin-forms-wrong-button-text-alignment-after-click-android/26089432#26089432))

I also tried this

```
public override void ChildDrawableStateChanged(View child)
{
    base.ChildDrawableStateChanged(child);

    Control.Text = Control.Text;
    Control.Checked = Control.Checked;
}
```

but still no fix

(I'm testing on a GT-I9505 with Android 4.4.2. The Version of the Xamarin.Forms Assemblies is 1.2.2.0)

Please help me,
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like I have to answer my own question.

I fixed the issue by adding a Height- and WidthRequest to the Switch in the xaml

Hope this helps someone else.
And maybe if you find a better solution, please let me know.

greetings~

Comment: Switch doesn't show up on 4.4 android for me unless you add a width and height request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the SelectedIndex to 0 (assuming there are values in the list) fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I also experience the same issue in Android 4.4 and below and only  visible once you add the height and width.However for lollipop is working without adding the height and width request .