# Text on button loses center alignment on changing of IsEnabled

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and testing this in the (really slow) Android Emulator.

When I start the login process I show an ActivityIndicator and then set a button to IsEnabled="false"

This correctly works and I can no longer press the button, but the text loses it's centering. It goes to the left.

e.g.

Here is the button on load (all is correct)

[image]

Next here it is when IsEnabled has been set to False. (Please note it looks darker because I have a StackLayout over this to grey out the screen but it makes no effect on the text alignment anyway.) But you can see its alignment loss.

[image]

Now here it is when IsEnabled is set back to true.

[image]

And here is the XAML.

```
<Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="#FFCF3838" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1" 
 Grid.Row="0" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="White" 
 IsEnabled="{Binding Path=LoginViewModel.IsLoginEnabled}"  Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

FYI - using MVVMLight however I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: this is a known issue :/

Comment: any workarounds available at the moment?

Comment: Still getting this issue 2 years later.

Comment: @LukeAlderton This issue was fixed a long time ago as far I am aware. Do you have HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" on your button or label?

Comment: I just tried and it has no effect.

Comment: Using Xamarin forms, it actually crashes the app adding that to the button in XAML. Says there's not a property by that name.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking of a Label. Anyway, I just tested this in 2.0.0 and it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **alignment** issue of the **Button** on **Android** that was in **v1.2.2x** of **Xamarin.Forms**.  A small example of how to trigger this bug can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056519/xamarin-forms-wrong-button-text-alignment-after-click-android/26089432#26089432).

I've just re-tested this on **Xamarin.Forms** **v1.2.3.6257** and the issue still exists.

**Xamarin** are aware of this issue though, and at present even though there have been suggested a couple work-arounds, none of these fully work.

There is a **version 1.3** that will be coming out.  As to whether this is going to be fixed for that release is another issue though.

The **version 1.3**. technical preview can be seen [here](http://www.infinite-x.net/2014/10/09/xamarin-forms-1-3-0-preview-formapplication/) and gives instructions for anyone who would like to possibly try this.

If you do, try it on another machine, as their **v.1.2.3 pre-release v4** caused me several bugs of which the roll-back wasn't as easy as it should had been.

It would be interesting to know, if anyone has the **v1.3 preview**, if they could run the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056519/xamarin-forms-wrong-button-text-alignment-after-click-android/26089432#26089432), and let us know the outcome of this currently on **v1.3** ?

The only other work-around for this, would be to replace the **Button** with a **custom renderer** for using a different **Button** control in its place.

Comment: I saw this on Lollipop, but it went away when I reverted to KitKat.

Comment: I'm still getting this on Xamarin.Forms 4.0 :/